# How can I pass a variable into the then clause of a promise

Tags: aurelia

I think I must have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere.  I'm using Aurelia to upload files to the server.  The first call creates a folder for the files and when that finishes I want to upload the files.  My code looks like this:

```
 if(myFiles.length !== 0 && myFiles !== null){
            this.data.createContainer(refNo)
            .then((response) => {
              this.data.upLoadFiles(refNo, myFiles)
            });
```

At the if statement myFiles contains the file list.  However when it gets to the this.data.upLoadFiles statement, myFiles is undefined.  I'm not sure the right way to do this.

Comment: Please provide more context over what this.data is and what Aurelia has to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

I fell victim to a less than complete understanding of promises.  The code to clean up after saving was executing before the promise was resolved.